# Custom error message on file attribute in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to give **custom error message** on **file** attribute.

Custom message for other attributes are working fine,but not working for file attribute.it display default error message.

Code in model file :

```
public function rules()
   {
       return [
           .....
           [['email', 'password'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
           ['email','email','message'=>'Invalid Email'],
           [['user_image'],'file', 'extensions'=>'svg,png,jpg,jpeg','message'=>'Only Images are allowed'],
           [['user_image'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
           .....
       ];
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-filevalidator.html#$wrongExtension-detail) the error message for wrong extension should be configured with `wrongExtension` key (`message` is for upload error)